# Using mysql I need to update changed records from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "Main" and "Import"

Import has the fields id, a, b, c, d

Main has the fields id, a, b, c, d, x, y, z

Main is the table used by my application and Import is a table that I dump data pulled from a web service.

For every entry in Import that already exists in Main (by id) I need to update Main if either a, b, c or d have changed without changing x, y or z (data added post import)

I currently have something like this

```
UPDATE Main, Import
Main.a = Import.a, 
Main.b = Import.b, 
Main.c = Import.c, 
Main.d = Import.d, 
WHERE 
Main.id = Import.id AND (
Main.a != Import.a OR 
Main.b != Import.b OR 
Main.c != Import.c OR 
Main.d != Import.d)
```

But wanted to know if there was any more elegant way of doing this.

My actual data is structured as above but has many more fields.

Comment: Is there a good reason you can't just join Import to Main when you use the data?  Duplicating data like that sort of defeats the object of having a database.

Comment: Import is a temporary store only.
I retrieve data from an external source and do preprocessing and cleaning on it in the import table.
I then update any new or modified entries (only a small percent) and then empty the Import DB ready for the next import from a different source.

Comment: Then why can't whatever's fetching the data insert it directly into Main?

Comment: You can use merge on the Id and update the main table.. It s faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a single table and use cron jobs to pull your data via web services while will return JSON and maintian array on your side for the data you got through web service then if any entry oid changed try to update that particular field....